# Can't set height of textarea in reactstrap card

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I'm using `reactstrap` in my project I have a simple `card` and I want to place a text area inside it using the following code:

```
<Card>
    <CardBody>
        <Form>
            <FormGroup>
                <Input
                    type="textarea"
                    defaultValue="Hello world"
                />
            </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    </CardBody>
</Card>
```

If I then try to set the height it just doesn't work. I have tried using `style`:

```
<Card>
    <CardBody>
        <Form>
            <FormGroup>
                <Input
                    type="textarea"
                    defaultValue={tweet.full_text}
                    style={{ height: 220 }}
                />
            </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    </CardBody>
</Card>
```

And also tried using a custom css class:

```
.text-area-custom {
  height: 220px;
}

<Card>
    <CardBody>
        <Form>
            <FormGroup>
                <Input
                    className="text-area-custom"
                    type="textarea"
                    defaultValue={tweet.full_text}
                />
            </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    </CardBody>
</Card>
```

Neither of these methods work. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `width: 220` means nothing without a unit. Is that meant to be `220km` or `220px` or `220inches`?

Comment: Is `<Input` a defined React component in your project? If you meant to use the HTML element directly then use `<input />` , not `<Input />` (note the uppercase vs lowercase `I`). Also, there is no `<input type="textarea" />`, that's a separate element: `<textarea></textarea>`.

Comment: @Dai unit is not required when using the `style` prop in react. For sizes is defaults to `px`.

Comment: `<Input>` is reactstrap component

Comment: @Kex if reactstrap uses styled components then it needs to be sure that it supports some properties like style.

Comment: Even if it doesn't support style the `className` method also doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try and set the rows attribute

```
<Card>
    <CardBody>
        <Form>
            <FormGroup>
                <Input
                    type="textarea"
                    defaultValue={tweet.full_text}
                    rows="5"
                />
            </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    </CardBody>
</Card>
```